# Pandas get_group method on DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby

Tags: python, pandas

**Question:** Does the get_group method work on a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby index?  If so, what is the appropriate syntax?

**Sample data:**

```
data = [[2, 4, 1, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)],
        [2, 4, 2, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5)], 
        [3, 4, 1, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 7)]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('abc') + ['dates'])

gb3 = df1.set_index('dates').groupby('a').resample('D')
DatetimeIndexResamplerGroupby [freq=<Day>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=e, base=0]

gb3.sum()

                  a   b   c
a   dates           
2   2017-01-01  2.0 4.0 1.0
    2017-01-02  NaN NaN NaN
    2017-01-03  NaN NaN NaN
    2017-01-04  NaN NaN NaN
    2017-01-05  2.0 4.0 2.0
3   2017-01-07  3.0 4.0 1.0
```

The get_group method is working for me on a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object`.
I've tried various approaches, the typical error is `TypeError: Cannot convert input [(0, 1)] of type <class 'tuple'> to Timestamp`

Comment: Maybe you could clarify your question a bit. FYI in pandas the most common way to group by time is to use the .resample() function, also you can check the documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: This comment is not helpful.  The DataFrame is 'resample('D')' as shown in the sample code.  What part of the question would you like clarification about?

Comment: As you didn't get any answer, I think it requires some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The below should be what you're looking for (if I understand the question correctly):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
​

data = [[2, 4, 1, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1)],
        [2, 4, 2, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 5)], 
        [3, 4, 1, datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 7)]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('abc') + ['dates'])
gb3 = df1.groupby(['a',pd.Grouper('dates')])
gb3.get_group((2, '2017-01-01'))
​
Out[14]:
a   b   c   dates
0   2   4   1   2017-01-01
```

I believe resample/pd.Grouper can be used interchangeably in this case (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, the following code returns the monthly values sum of the year 2015

```
df.resample('MS').sum().resample('Y').get_group('2015-12-31')
```